# Wrap async usage with Meteor

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

I'm trying to wrap an async function inside my Meteor app.
To make it maximum simple I will try to make a basic example (because all I found was kinda more complex that i actly need).

In my app I am trying to do

```
console.log("1");
my_func(string_to_display);
console.log("2");
```

As node is async I get logs 1 and 2 before to see the string i sent to the function.

I tried to call it this way

```
var my_func_sync = Meteor.wrapAsync(my_fync);
var result = my_func_sync(string_to_display);
```

Most examples here are more complex, with URLs and calls between server/client/other services. I would like to know if there is a way to wrap a simple function that will only send my string to console. Could anyone give me a most basic example ever please? Would be highly appreciated!

Comment: let me get this right. you want to print "1", then get the string and then print "2"?

Comment: Can you please add a async function example which you think reflects best your idea? Based on this we can tell you best whether to use `wrapAsync` or `bindEnvironment` or `fibers/future` directy.

Answer (score 0):

I guess using async await can sort the issue.

```
async my_funct1(){
    console.log("1");
    await my_func(string_to_display);
    console.log("2");
}
```

Note that you will need to use async with my_funct1() if you need to use await. This will typically wait for the call to return back from myfunc(string_to_display) to proceed to the next line.